# Display different Devise flash message on first login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Is it possible to display a flash message that says something like 'Welcome!' the first time a user logs in?

Comment: Yes. Do you actually have a problem doing so? Can you post the code you have and explain your issue in doing that?

Comment: I have no idea how to go about doing something like that. I searched for it and didn't find a way to keep the current 'Successfully signed in' message, but display a welcome message on first login.

Comment: Share the code which you use to auth users, controllers, views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
if current_user && current_user.sign_in_count == 1
  unless session[:display_welcome]
    flash.now[:notice] = "Welcome!"
    session[:display_welcome] = true
  end
end
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much. Is there a reason why setting a session variable is necessary?

Comment: Because it will keep showing welcome message wherever the user navigates after first login

Comment: It would be useful to see some context for this code, e.g. Which file it should go in.